# Load external json data into html form

Tags: jquery, html, json, forms

How can i load a external JSON file?

**Note: It is also possible that external files are blocked by server settings.**

**Fill out forms from local JSON**

```
<form id="datas-from-json">                        
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control">Name:</label>
        <input name="nameCustomer" class="form-control" type="text" autofocus>
        ...
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  for(key in json) {
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(key))
      $('input[name='+key+']').val(json[key]);
  }

  // JSON
  var json={
    "nameCustomer": "Madmann",
    "surnameCustomer": "Max",
    "room": "32322",
    "telephone": "223231",
    "email": "info@blabla.com",
    "website": "www.blabla.com",
    "address": "Main Street 422",
    "sector": "1A"
  };

  </script>
```

**Fill out forms from local JSON File**

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
  $.getJSON('data.json',
    function(data) {        
        for(key in data) {
          if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
            $('input[name='+key+']').val(data[key]);
          }
    });
  });
```

**Fill out forms from external JSON File**

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
  $.getJSON('http://www.example.net/data.json',
    function(data) {        
        for(key in data) {
          if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
            $('input[name='+key+']').val(data[key]);
          }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the browser's console? How exactly does `data.json` look like, and where is it located?

Comment: If your json in the file includes `var json=` then it isn't valid json and that part needs to be removed

Comment: The data.json is located local within windows folder. It's a XMLHttpRequest-Error: _Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https._

if I put the file online, then it works.

Comment: I think you have three problems that need solving. 1 fetching data without errors (not scope of this question, 2 building a form from json, filled with values (or empty values) and 3 targeting specific fields with updates. 
Structure is simple key-val pairs and input will be standard input fields. 1 can't be solved by us here, but 2 and 3 can.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('folder/data.json',
    function(JSONdata) {
      for (key in JSONdata) {
        if (JSONdata.hasOwnProperty(key))
          $('input[name=' + key + ']').val(JSONdata[key]);
      }
    });
});
```

and the customized file data.json (see comment from [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl)):

```
{
    "nameCustomer": "Madmann",
    "surnameCustomer": "Max",
    "room": "32322",
    "telephone": "223231",
    "email": "info@blabla.com",
    "website": "www.blabla.com",
    "address": "Main Street 422",
    "sector": "1A"
};
```

I think I had server problems in between, so the other bugs.

Comment: I think it was a internal server problem, that has forbidden to load the "external" file. This was e.g. when trying to load a http://www.